# XCode4 - Change the icon of the program

Tags: xcode4

I have written a program on XCode4, how can I change the icon of the program?
Refer to the screen capture  below:

[image]

Also, what is the size for the icon?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put icon file into Resources folder, and then open .plist file (also in resouces folder). Set icon file name in properties list.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the size for the icon?

Comment: Check the [`details`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW7) here.